# DHCP discover in scapy

Tags: python, networking, scapy, dhcp

I'm writing some Python code with scapy to send a DHCP discover packet, but I'm falling short with the theory behind what I'm doing:

DHCP is an Application Layer protocol sent over UDP, so instinctively I would build the packet as `Ether(...)/IP(...)/UDP(...)/DHCP(...)` but unfortunately, browsing on the internet, I can only find packets with an additional BOOTP layer: `Ether(...)/IP(...)/UDP(...)/BOOTP(...)/DHCP(...)`

Wikipedia presents DHCP as an evolution of BOOTP, so why the correct packet formation contains both of them?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like DHCP is only an **extension** of BOOTP, and BOOTP clients can interoperate with DHCP servers without any problem.

[This](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2131#section-2) is a useful source for detailed information